# Finding the area between two curves given a graph

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given the following question along with this graph as a question. I did the question, but had some difficulty with the fact that the graph dips below the $x$-axis. After thinking about it further, the graph seems to me to be completely wrong - the shape is correct but the numbers are totally off. Is this true? 
And, **how do you find the area between two curves when they dip below the $x$-axis?**

[image]

Comment: Hint: Since $f(x)$ is on top and $g(x)$ is in the bottom, $f(x)-g(x)$ gives you the height.

Comment: usually if you are asked to find area, all areas are considered positive values.

Comment: I know how to solve it. I just want to know if there is anything different when it dips below the $x$-axis

Comment: @Vasya does that mean I should add the amount it is below the axis?

Comment: No. To convince more, imagine two points $(5, 4)$ and $(5, -2)$. Find the vertical distance between them. Which expression do you use to find the distance?

Comment: You can safely ignore the x axis. You would need to split up the integral in the event that two curves intersected each other between $x=1$ and $x=k$ (which does not happen.)

Comment: I see. The fact that (5,-2) is below the x axis makes no difference.

Comment: You have it! If $(x, y_1)$ is below $(x, y_2)$, then $y_2-y_1$ gives the distance between them. You don't have to worry about $x$ axis

Comment: About the graph I gave above - am I correct in thinking it is incorrect?

Comment: The numbers on the graph look correct, can you see that $k=4$?

Comment: but when $x=4$ then $x^4-6x+7$ does not equal -1?

Comment: @burt: in general case you just take the integral of the absolute value of differences between curves but in your case (as people noted) one curve is always above the other so no need to use absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

The two curves intersect at the points
$(1,2)$ and $(4,-1)$.

We can check that
$$f(1)=g(1) \text{ and } f(4)=g(4).$$

The curve of $f$ is over the curve of $g$, so the difference $f-g$ is positive and the integral
$$A=\int_1^4(f(x)-g(x))dx$$
will give you the desired area.

If you do it well, you will find that
$$A=\frac{9}{2}.$$